# How to use the search bar to filter static tableview rows in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an app that requires me to create static table-view rows, and I need a way to use the search bar to filter the results. I can only find information on how to do this with dynamic table view cells.

Comment: http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/

Comment: TableViews are typically populated from a tableView DataSource - generally an array. One way is to keep a main array, which contains all of your static data, and then a second array which is used as the datasource. As the searchField is typed into, filter the main array to obtain the second array (the datasource) and the reload your tableview.